# Cannot get expo Push Notification Token in build Android app. (working on the development environment)

Tags: react-native, expo

In the development environment (when app is running in the android device via QR Code) the push notification token is retrieved successfully. But after building the app and installed to the same device the token is not retrieved.

I'm using the example code given in Expo docs to get the token.

```
useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotifications();
  }, [])

registerForPushNotifications = async () => {
    if (Constants.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        finalStatus = status;
      }

      const token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

      let body = new FormData();
      body.append('token', token);

      await ApiPublicForm.post('token/index.php', body)
        .then(function (response) {
          // console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // console.log(error);
        });

    } else {
      alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('default', {
        name: 'default',
        sound: true,
        priority: 'max',
        vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      });
    }
  };
```

my app.json

```
"android": {
  "permissions": [
    "NOTIFICATIONS"
  ],
  "versionCode": 3
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer for the question
You have to follow the steps mention in this link to work push notifications in standalone apps https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/